# Using the phrase "Wisdom of the day"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions

Is it appropriate to use the phrase "Wisdom of the day" in a sentence in the following context?

"Social distancing is the wisdom of the day"

I've heard the phrase being used before, but it feels somewhat clunky. I couldn't find any other instances of the phrase being used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxford English Dictionary (on line behind paywall)

> 1.d. Contextually, usually predicative with following infinitive: **= a wise thing to do**; also with 'a' and plural, a piece of wisdom; a wise action or proceeding. (Opposed to folly n.1 1c) archaic.
>
> 1362   W. Langland Piers Plowman A. vii. 201   *Here nou..and holde hit for wisdam.* [Listen... and accept it as wisdom.]
>
> ...
>
> 1831   W. Scott Count Robert vii, in Tales of my Landlord 4th Ser. II. 183   *It is wisdom to choose a better protector.*

1884   H. H. Jackson Ramona i   *If she had ever said anything about herself, which she never did—one of her many wisdoms.*

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, the sentence isn't wrong. Is that a fair conclusion to make?

Comment: Yes. It is a little formal but correct.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it sounded a bit archaic.